# Android - ADB server hangs and does not respond

Tags: android, adb

ADB server hangs and does not respond for any commands. No output seen after executing any commands. Below is the adb logs seen while executing the commands

```
adb devices
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_trace.cpp:178] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_trace.cpp:178] Revision 5943271ace17-android
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_trace.cpp:178]
List of devices attached
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_client.cpp:271] adb_query: host:devices
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_client.cpp:124] _adb_connect: host:version
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_io.cpp:101] writex: fd=5 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_io.cpp:75] readx: fd=5 wanted=4
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_io.cpp:91] readx: fd=5 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_client.cpp:157] _adb_connect: return fd 5
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_client.cpp:165] adb_connect: service host:devices
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_io.cpp:75] readx: fd=5 wanted=4
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_io.cpp:91] readx: fd=5 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_io.cpp:75] readx: fd=5 wanted=4
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_io.cpp:91] readx: fd=5 wanted=4 got=4 30303237 0027
adb I 06-15 23:37:42  9349 1403933 adb_client.cpp:124] _adb_connect: host:devices
```

no output seen beyond this. After killing java process, it started working again.

Need to understand what caused this issue and why killing java process resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just kill adb background process and restart your android studio. hope it will work
 thanks :)

Comment: Tried this multiple times and didn't work. Only after killing java process, it did work